# Finding what the sum of $(2^n)(3^{(-n+1)})$ from $n=1$ to infinity converges to

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponentiation

Sorry for the lack of math symbols but I'm trying to find what the sum of
$f(x)=(2^n)(3^{-n+1})$ from $n=1$ to infinity converges to. I have tried using the sequence of partial sums but I'm too stupid to find what Sn is equal to in order to take the limit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is $(x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + \cdots x^n) \times (1-x)$?  For $|x|<1,$ what is $\lim_{n\to\infty} x^{(n+1)}$?

Comment: infinity right?

Comment: Please edit the math in your query with [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: [Here is a tutorial on how to typeset mathematical symbols in this site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please use it. Also, please include all information in the *body* of the post; you don't start letters on the envelope, you shouldn't start posts on the subject line.

Comment: More like $\frac{1}{\infty}$.  Try it with $x = \frac{1}{2}$, and see what happens.

Comment: I think you would have been more receptive to the answers you got if you had written out four or five of the terms, to get a feel for what they are doing.  Yes, as you discovered (see below), it is a *geometric series* you are dealing with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Define $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n\cdot3^{-n+1}.$$

Observe that $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n\cdot3^{-n+1}=-2^0\cdot3^{-0+1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^n\cdot3^{-n+1}=-3+\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^n\cdot3^{-n+1}}_{:=S_0}.$$
Rewrite the summand:
$$S_0=3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{3^{n}}=3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n.$$
By the geometric series this equal to $$\frac{3}{1-\frac{2}{3}}=9.$$ Since
$S=S_0-3$, the final answer is $S=6$.

Comment: thank you @vitamin d for offering actual help, I think I get it now. I needed to use a geometric series instead of solving by definition

Comment: @Wh1tl0w This is correct :). If my answer has helped you, I'd appreciate a checkmark.

Answer (score -1):

$2^n3^{-n+1} = 2^n3^{-(n-1)} =2^n\cdot \frac 1{3^{n-1}} = 2^n\cdot \frac {3}{3^{n}} = 3\cdot \frac {2^n}{3^n} = 3(\frac 23)^n$.

So we need $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 3\cdot (\frac 23)^n$.

Can you take from there?

> Well known formula: If $|r| < r$ then $\sum_{n=\color{green}0}^{\infty} r^n = \frac 1{1-r}$. (Note the base step is $n = \large{\color{green}0}$ and not $n=\large{\color{red}1}$).

Derivation if you didn't know the above result.

> $(1 + r + r^2 + r^3 + ........+r^m)(1-r) = $
>  $(1 + r + r^2 + r^3 + ........+r^m) - (r+ r^2 + r^3 + r^4 + ...... + r^{m+1})=$
>  $1 - r^{m+1}$. So
>
>  $ (1 + r + r^2 + r^3 + ........+r^m) =\frac {1-r^{m+1}}{1-r}$
>
>  if $|r| < 1$ then $\lim_{m\to \infty} r^{m+1} = 0$ so
>
>  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^k =\lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^m r^k = \lim_{m\to \infty}\frac {1-r^m}{1-r} = \frac 1{1-r}$.

Actual Answer (but only read if you *really, really, really* need it!)

> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 3\cdot (\frac 23)^n =$
>   $3 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac 23)^n = $
>   $3([\sum_{n=\color{red}{\large 0}}^{\infty}(\frac 23)^n]- (\frac 23)^{\color{red}{\large 0}}) =$
>  $3(\frac 1{1-\frac 23} - 1)=3(\frac 1{\frac 13} - 1)=3(3-1)=3\cdot 2 = 6$

====

Might be useful to try to calculate

$2^1\cdot 3^{-1+1} + 2^2 \cdot 3^{-2+1} + ..........  + 2^m \cdot 3^{-m+1}$ for a finite $m$.

> $2^1\cdot 3^{-1+1} + 2^2 \cdot 3^{-2+1} + ..........  + 2^m \cdot 3^{-m+1}=$
>
>  $(2^1\cdot 3^{-1+1} + 2^2 \cdot 3^{-2+1} + ..........  + 2^m \cdot 3^{-m+1} )\frac {1-\frac 23}{1-\frac 23} =$
>
>  $\frac {(2^1\cdot 3^{-1+1} + 2^2 \cdot 3^{-2+1} + ..........  + 2^m \cdot 3^{-m+1} )(1- \frac 23)}{\frac 13} =$
>
>  $3\cdot   (2^1\cdot 3^{-1+1} + 2^2 \cdot 3^{-2+1} + ..........  + 2^m \cdot 3^{-m+1} )(1- \frac 23)=$
>
>  $3[(2^1\cdot 3^{-1+1} + 2^2 \cdot 3^{-2+1} + ..........  + 2^m \cdot 3^{-m+1} )- (2^2 \cdot 3^{-2+1} + 2^3 \cdot 3^{-3+1} + ........ + 2^{m+1}\cdot 3^{-m})]=$
>
>  $3[2^1 \cdot 3^{-1+1} - 2^{m+1}\cdot 3^{-m})]=$
>
>  $3[2 - 2\cdot \frac {2^m}{3^m}]=$
>
>  $6 - 6(\frac 23)^m$.
>
>  As $6(\frac 23)^m \to 0$
>
>  we get the infinite sum is $6$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally get it. one question though, how did you get to 3(2/3)^n from the original equation?

Comment: Is that not clear? $2^n3^{-n+1} = 2^n3^{-(n-1)} =2^n\cdot \frac 1{3^{n-1}} = 2^n\cdot \frac {3}{3^{n}} = 3\cdot \frac {2^n}{3^n}$

Comment: where does the minus one go? again I'm kinda dumb

Comment: $\frac 1{3^{n-1}} = \frac {3^1}{3^{n-1}\cdot 3^1} =\frac 3{3^{(n-1)+1}} = \frac 3{3^n}$ ...OR.... $\frac 1{3^{n-1}} = \frac 1{3^n\cdot 3^{-1}} = \frac 1{3^n\cdot 13} = \frac 3{3^n}$.